# Partitions of integers with finite uses in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

I've done some research into partitions and am yet to find any resources to understand the following:

Given a number $n$ and the restrictions that:

- Using only the numbers $1, 2, ..., m$;
- A maximum of $p$ times per number.

How many ways are there to add together these numbers to be less than or equal to $n$.

As an example using $n = 5, m = 3,$ and $p = 2$.

You can find:

- $1$
- $1 + 1, 2$
- $2 + 1, 3$ (not $1 + 1 + 1$)
- $2 + 1 + 1, 2 + 2, 3 + 1$
- $3 + 1 + 1, 2 + 2 + 1, 3 + 2$

so the answer here would be $1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 = 11$

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use generating functions and say it is the sum of the coefficients of $x^1$ through $x^n$ of the expansion of $\prod\limits_{k=1}^m\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^px^{ik}\right)$... I don't believe you'll find a much cleaner approach for the fully general problem.

Comment: For an alternative, you could use recurrence relations of several variables, saying that $f(n,m,p) = f(n-m,m-1,p)+f(n-2m,m-1,p)+\dots+f(n-pm,m-1,p)$ and noting that $f(n,m,p)=0$ for $n<0$... but this seems horribly tedious to actually use...

Comment: I suspect there isn't an efficient general solution. As for the recurrence relation, that is equivalent to the problem I'm trying to find a better solution for which is eliminating the nodes (or discovering how many there are) where n < 0 on a graph representing a variant of a subtraction game. Thanks for the help. @JMoravitz